# CSS Horizontal List Spacing

Tags: css, horizontallist

I'm creating an infinite horizontal list but there is a strange spacing being inserted into the list when I add the CSS style `white-scape: nowrap;`
This style is being applied to the class `.carouselList`

When I take out that style the spacing goes back to normal, but then I don't have a horizontal list anymore.
Please see the example on fiddleJS https://jsfiddle.net/manneh00/yvhz3s3p/2/

Answer (score 0):

for the big space try remove `margin-right:15px;`

```
.carouselListItem {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 224px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

I hope this will help